# Is Visual Odometry affected by the performance of the computer?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, rgbd, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried the /demo_rgbd http://wiki.ros.org/demo_rgbd  on ROS indigo in order to do a visual odometry. Since, according to the KITTI website, this method is one of the best, i don't obtain good results...Lots of drifts and at the end the point of departure is far from the point of arrival.
Even with the dataset provided by the authors, I got bad results whereas their video show good results.

I tried to understand why and except for the number of features maybe, i don't understand. And then, I wonder if the bad results can be influenced by the performance of the computer ? Indeed, according to the ROS wiki, they tell that they tested the algorithm with 4 core and almost 3GHz. My computer has only 2 core and 2.5 Ghz.

If yes, how i can improve the performance ?

Thank,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206471/is-visual-odometry-affected-by-the-performance-of-the-computer-?/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes there is definitely a minimum amount of CPU requred to process visual odometry. If you do not have enough processing available you need to either downsample the image, use fewer features or lower the frame rate. All of which will decrease accuracy and performance. But if you don't have the CPU available you can't use it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-04-05**:
Okey thank you, maybe that's explain my results.